# How do I find the time complexity of these 3 nested loops?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

The task is to analyze the following algorithm and calculate its time complexity.

I solved it as taking nested loops are 3 so `O(n^3)`.

How do I solve this problem?

```
MSS (A[], N)              //Where N is size of array A[]
{
    int temp  = 0, MS  = 0;
    For (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < N; j++)
        {         
            temp  = 0;
            for(int k = i; k <= j; k++)
                        temp = temp +  A[k];
            if(temp > MS)
                        MS = temp;
        }
    }
    return(MS);
}
```

Comment: 1st you need to do is to tell what operations are you counting. Then count them properly. There will be 3 sums, but it does not mean necessarily its O(n^3).

Comment: I also did some working by searching material regarding complexities and after reading them i solved as follows:
first for loops from[1-N]
the next for loop has different behavior so it might be log n
last for loop is like second for loop so combining all these i have n^2log(n). But i am confused about its accuracy. Kindly share our Knowledge.

Comment: @user3602001... Did you read some text about `O notation`? read it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can proceed formally as such:

[image]